# A single data structure to store object that has different search parameters

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

So I have a list of objects, say a list of Students with variables like `username`, `roll number`, `standard`, `division`, etc.

I am looking out for a data structure that can store student objects and also allows search on any of the above variables. The time complexity is the key part here as there will be thousands of the searches done on the data.

Ex: If I use Binary Tree, then I can take a hashcode of the any variable say, `username` and then take an index out of it and store the student object in the Binary Tree. However, this has a limitation, as say if I want to search the student on the `standard` then it is not possible as the index at which the Student is stored in the Binary Tree was generated from `username`.

Is there any data structure, that can allow storing student once and also allows searching student on the different variables. OR Any hybrid data structure that can be created to fulfill the requirement.

I'd like to achieve a time complexity of `O(1)` at best else `O(log n)`.

Comment: It is already implemented with database and NoSQL database why you want to do that in your program without using them?

Comment: @tashkhisi So it is needed to be done in memory as say we are performing this back to back in a batch job with thousands of records.

Comment: What is the most complex query and most frequent query that you will have to support?

Comment: Also, what is the size of your dataset (i.e. how many students and the size of each student record)?

Comment: On avg, there will 10K records on which the search will be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all students that have a particular `roll number` or particular `standard`, then you could maintain a many hashmaps to students:

```
HashMap<Standard, List[Student]>
HashMap<RollNumber, List[Student]>
HashMap<Username, Student>        (assuming usernames are unique)
```

For some fields (e.g. roll number, standard) that are just integers, you could use an array instead of a HashMap.

However, if you want to find to support queries like "find all students in a standard 5 whose roll numbers are between 5 and 10", then you'd have to do a lookup in two hashmaps and intersect the values.

If you want these operations to be quick, [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) might help.

Comment: The idea of HashMap is not the right choice because the of the internal data structure of the HashMap, ex: If there are thousands of records stored in the HashMap, there will for sure be index collisions, that will create a LinkedList inside the HashMap and the time complexity will be worst i.e O(N).

Also, creating different `HashMap` for each variable increases the space complexity. 

In KDTree, I can store data on multiple variables, however, the searches are also done using multiple variables only and not one or less than the dimensions.

Comment: Note that although the worst case time complexity of HashMap search is O(N), the average case is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this, I would create an array of `Student`s, where the index of each `Student` would be its ID.

Then, I would create a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to map the `username` to an ID, another `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to map `roll number` to an ID, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Considering username, roll numbers are unique for every student and standard, divisions can be shared by multiple students.

You can work out a solution in fallowing manner to achieve the O(1)/O(log(N))/O(N) depending upon the cases.

Lets define the class structure first :

```
class Student{

  // Considering all the variables to be string. You can change them according to your use cases.

  String username;

  String rollNumber;

  String standard;

  String division;

}
```

Lets create some maps to store these students

```
Map<String, Student> usernameMap; // username to object map

Map<String, Student> rollNumberMap; // roll number to object map
```

Whenever any Student objectis created you add those respective Maps.

Incase you want to find out all the Students in any given standard/division,

you can keep the another mapping for standards and divisions also.

Something like ->

```
Map<String, Set<String>> standardMap; // standard to set of student's username/rollnumber.
```

you can create similarly map for divisions.

Comment: Only username is unique, all other params can be repeated, say two different students from different standards or divisions can be the same.

There will also be scenarios, where I'd want to search if two different students have same roll number in the same std and division.